# Error: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data: '0'

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart, r-caret

I am trying to perform a CART with caret package but I have this error continously.

```
train_control<-trainControl(method="LOOCV")
model<-train(clase ~ ., data=mydata, trControl=train_control, method="rpart")
```

> Error: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data: '0'

This is gene expression data so there are a lot of "0" y in my data but I want to preserve it because this is information.

Comment: Please show the results of `summary(mydata)`

Comment: Categorical variables are converted into dummy variables, i.e. columns with 0 and 1. Some of those columns have only zero values i.e. these levels are not seen anywhere in your data and thus they do not provide any information to the model.